# Why is copying many files with Caja much slower than compressing+copying+uncompressing?

Tags: filesystems, file-copy, compression, caja

I am currently working with [HASYv2 dataset](https://zenodo.org/record/259444) which contains the hasy-data directory with 168.233 images of size 32px x 32px. I just wanted to copy that directory with Caja, but I skipped this after about 5 minutes (and Ubuntu told me it would take another 10 minutes).

Copying the files with `cp -a source_dir target_dir` took less than 9 seconds.

However, creating a tar.bz2 archive, copying the archive, extracting the files was done within about 15 seconds (everything combined).

Why is that the case?

(Side questions: When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to copy files within Caja the copying process is started by Caja, right? Does it make sense to internally use a similar procedure if many files are about to be copied?)

Comment: I wonder how fast `cp -a` would have been. Possibly faster then the `tar`. Or perhaps there's a slow network involved so the reduced file size (due to the compression) outweighed the transfer time. Without some more context it's difficult to provide concrete answers.

Comment: @roaima `cp -a` was done in `8,17s` (which is likely faster than `tar` was). I've copied it on one machine to the same disk on that machine.

Comment: So to clarify, Caja took about 15 minutes whereas `cp -a` took 8s for the same data? Then the question isn't why copying files is slow, but why Caja is slow at copying files. Please edit your question to clarify. I don't know Caja, but this may be because the files are images and it extracts metadata from the images when it sees them appear.

Comment: @Gilles I've changed the title / the text a bit.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention: were the files in the cache after your first attempt? The difference could be that a read cache→write buffer copy is a lot faster than a disk→write buffer copy.

Comment: I just did the copying with cp again after shutting down the pc: `12,40s`. Still several orders of magnitude faster than copying with Caja.

Comment: There is a similar issue for deleting a directory with many files - while `rm -r` use `unlinkat` system call to remove item in opened directory, caja/nautilus removes each file separately - I guess there will be similar issue with copying directories...
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/1904